# My GitHub repository is updated but my published GitHub page won't update. Why is this?

Tags: github, repository, updating

Similar questions have been asked but I haven't been able to find my answer:
My site is fine locally and all the correct files seem to be on my GitHub, but my published site (https://username.github.io/project) is still only showing my first intitial push.

Can someone direct me to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

From "[Configuring a publishing source for GitHub Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)"

- make sure you have enabled GitHub Pages to publish your site from master or gh-pages

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pages/none-source-setting.png]

- or that you are one a `master` branch, subfolder `docs`.

Then you might need to wait a minute or two before seeing those pages rendered.